# Ubuntu : Automatically start GUI application at startup

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-20.04, touchscreen, startupscript

I would like to start a GUI application when the session starts

It is a CM4 with a 5 inch touch screen, the purpose is to launch an application when Ubuntu starts.

Via a terminal, when I start it (./main) it works without problem

- I tried via startup applications but it doesn't work, I don't know why
- I tried via systemd but it doesn't seem to work for graphical applications

```sh
[Unit]
After=network.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/path/main

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- I tried via /etc/rc5.d but that doesn't work either

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the content of your `main` script?

Comment: This is an application built with LVGL

Comment: So it is not a script, but a binary, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it's a binary